# Overlapping tikz pictures in a minipage environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I move the first gird in the following to the left so that it doesn't overlap with the second please?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}
\flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,draw,
every odd row/.style={align=right},every evenrow/.style={align=left},
nodes={text width=1.3cm},row sep=0.1cm,column sep=0.2cm] 
          (m) {3&0&0\\3&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&1\\};
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.north east)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.south west)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 1 player};
\node[left=2.5cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,draw,
every odd row/.style={align=right},every evenrow/.style={align=left},
nodes={text width=1.3cm},row sep=0.1cm,column sep=0.2cm] 
          (m) {2&0&0\\2&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\\0&0&3\\};
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.north east)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.south west)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 2 player};
\node[left=2.5cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Group 2 player};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,draw,
every odd row/.style={align=right},every evenrow/.style={align=left},
nodes={text width=1.3cm},row sep=0.1cm,column sep=0.2cm] 
          (m) {2&0&0\\3&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\\0&0&1\\};
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.north east)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.south west)$) 
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 2 player};
\node[left=2.5cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\label{normal}
\caption{cap here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally on SE, minimal working examples are provided so that everyone can test your code right away...
This code won't even compile if I add a preamble and a \begin{document} resp. \end{document}...

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code to be a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wide images to be fit in `minipages`, so they protrude outside them and consequently overlap each other. One solution can be rotate text on the left side of matrix. With this I obtain the following picture:

[image]

I slightly modified your code (in attempt to make it more readable), however I'm not yet satisfied with result. The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{
every odd row/.style={align=right},
every evenrow/.style={align=left},
        }
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}
    \flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, draw,
nodes={text width=1.3cm},row sep=0.1cm,column sep=0.2cm]
          (m) {3&0&0\\3&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&1\\};
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.north east)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.south west)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 1 player};
\node[left=of m.west,align=center,anchor=center,
      rotate=90] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, draw,
        nodes={text width=1.3cm, outer sep=0pt},
        row sep=0.1cm, column sep=0.2cm]
          (m) 
{2&0&0\\2&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\\0&0&3\\};
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2}%
{
\draw ($(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$ |-m.north)
        -- ($(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$ |-m.south);
\draw ($(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$ -| m.west)
        -- ($(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$ -| m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] 
            at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.north east)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] 
            at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.south west)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 2 player};
\node[left=of m.west,align=center,anchor=center,
      rotate=90] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","C"}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,draw,
nodes={text width=1.3cm},row sep=0.1cm,column sep=0.2cm]
          (m) {2&0&0\\3&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3\\0&0&1\\};
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.north east)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/6}!(m.south west)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 2 player};
\node[left=of m.west,align=center,anchor=center,
      rotate=90] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}

\label{normal}
\caption{cap here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
I don't know for the background, why is your MWE written on (to my opinion) so complicated way. See, if the MWE below is usable for you. In it I try to optimize it to image above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\tikzset{
every odd row/.style={align=right},
every evenrow/.style={align=left},
row sep=0.0cm, column sep=0.0cm
        }
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}
    \flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, draw, inner sep=0pt,
        nodes={text width=1.5cm,
               inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0pt},
        ]   (m)
{3&0&0\\ 3&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&1\\};
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(2*\i)] in {1,2}
{
\draw (m-1-\i.north east) -- (m-6-\i.south east);
\draw (m-\j-1.south west) -- (m-\j-3.south east);
}
% A B C
    \foreach \x [count=\i,
                 evaluate=\i as \j using int(2*\i),
                 evaluate=\i as \k using int(\j-1)] in {A,B,C}
{
\node[above=2mm of m-1-\i.north] {\x};
\node[left=2mm of $(m-\j-1.west)!0.5!(m-\k-1.west)$] {\x};
}
% players
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 1 player};
\node[left=of m.west,align=center,anchor=center,
      rotate=90] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{6cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, draw, inner sep=0pt,
        nodes={text width=1.5cm, 
               inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0pt},
        ]   (m) 
{2&0&0\\    2&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&3\\ 0&0&3\\};
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(2*\i)] in {1,2}
{
\draw (m-1-\i.north east) -- (m-6-\i.south east);
\draw (m-\j-1.south west) -- (m-\j-3.south east);
}
% A B C
    \foreach \x [count=\i,
                 evaluate=\i as \j using int(2*\i),
                 evaluate=\i as \k using int(\j-1)] in {A,B,C}
{
\node[above=2mm of m-1-\i.north] {\x};
\node[left=2mm of $(m-\j-1.west)!0.5!(m-\k-1.west)$] {\x};
}
% players
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 2 player};
\node[left=of m.west,align=center,anchor=center,
      rotate=90] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, draw, inner sep=0pt,
        nodes={text width=1.5cm,
               inner sep=2mm, outer sep=0pt},
        ]   (m)
{2&0&0\\    3&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&3\\ 0&0&1\\};
% lines
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(2*\i)] in {1,2}
{
\draw (m-1-\i.north east) -- (m-6-\i.south east);
\draw (m-\j-1.south west) -- (m-\j-3.south east);
}
% A B C
    \foreach \x [count=\i,
                 evaluate=\i as \j using int(2*\i),
                 evaluate=\i as \k using int(\j-1)] in {A,B,C}
{
\node[above=2mm of m-1-\i.north] {\x};
\node[left=2mm of $(m-\j-1.west)!0.5!(m-\k-1.west)$] {\x};
}
% players
\node[above=24pt of m.north] (firm b) {Group 2 player};
\node[left=of m.west,align=center,anchor=center,
      rotate=90] {Group 1 player};
\end{tikzpicture}

\label{normal}
\caption{cap here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```